# RTOS-rtx (CMSIS) - Synchronizing threads

Tags: rtx-rtos

In the given Image, there is a program I'm having a difficulty to understand.
If we have created two threads count & barrier then why are we defining "counter"(2nd line)

also, inside thred1 function we are creating count as a thread. someone please differentiate between 'count' & 'counter'. what I've understood is count it a global variable and counter is a thread but I'm confused between their usability and how they are used in this given program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the first line should be: osSemaphoreId counter,barrier. Then counter and barrier refer to (are Ids of) semaphores, count is just an integer that counts the threads that have completed.

Comment: @Icy but again in 'thread1' they have created semaphores with 'count' which should have been 'counter' the way they have done with 'barrier'

Comment: yes, I agree - this was obviously not tested code.